# Iterate over list items in a specific order

Tags: python

I need to perform an iteration which outputs all the instances where a player played his former team. So far I have:

```
teams = ['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4']

for previous_team, curr_team in zip(teams, teams[1:]):
    print (curr_team, previous_team)
```

which prints:

```
'team2', 'team1'
'team3', 'team2'
'team4', 'team3'
```

But I need a wider scope, where the player has not played only the very last team, but also teams more distant in the past, contemplating all intervals back to index 0, ending up with:

```
'team2', 'team1'
'team3', 'team2'
'team4', 'team3'
'team3', 'team1'   <----
'team4', 'team2'   <----
'team4', 'team1    <----
```

This is the logic, and should be applied to a list of n items.

---

How do I do this?

Comment: sorry it was a typo, fixed

Comment: Also in your desired output there is a repetition `'team4', 'team3'`

Comment: what do you mean? Do you want all possible combinations?

Comment: @Andreas no, only all combinations from the last to the first item, backwards.

Comment: You forgot the apostrophe on the last line

Comment: All you need is `itertools.combinations(teams, 2)`.  That will produce an iterator.  If you want to force a list, use `list(itertools.combinations(teams, 2))`.  The order of the pairs may be reversed from what was shown, but if that matters, just use the reverse of `teams`.

Comment: @8-BitBorges It would probably be easier to do it in the following order: `(2,1), (3,2), (3,1), (4,3), (4,2), (4,1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if what you want is all combinations

```
from itertools import combinations
teams = ['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4']

for combo in combinations(teams, 2):  # 2 for pairs, 3 for triplets, etc
    print(combo)
```

('team1', 'team2')

('team1', 'team3')

('team1', 'team4')

('team2', 'team3')

('team2', 'team4')

('team3', 'team4')

Comment: if list length is not known a priori, would `for combo in combinations(teams, len(teams)):`do it?

Comment: @8-BitBorges The second parameter is the length of the tuples in the output list. In your case it should be just `2`, no need to use `len` here.

Comment: @8-BitBorges From what I can see, `combinations` will return a different result to what you wanted to get. You are probably looking for this: `map(reversed, combinations(teams, 2))`.

Comment: this solution has a problem `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file test.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details` when performing with strings

Comment: try addd this in the first line of the code:

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Answer (score 0):

Naives approach is to have 2 loop over your team and then reduce the second list with the first element at each loop

So :

```
for i in range(len(team)):
    for j in range(len(team)-i):
       print(team[i],team[j+i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using comprehension, also removing the same team value if occurred twice within the list.

```
teams = ['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4']

[(team1, team2) for team1 in teams for team2 in teams if team1 != team2]
```

Result:

```
[('team1', 'team2'), ('team1', 'team3'), ('team1', 'team4'), ('team2', 'team1'), ('team2', 'team3'), ('team2', 'team4'), ('team3', 'team1'), ('team3', 'team2'), ('team3', 'team4'), ('team4', 'team1'), ('team4', 'team2'), ('team4', 'team3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `product`:

```py
import itertools

teams = ["team1", "team2", "team3", "team4"]

matches = itertools.product(teams, repeat=2)

print(list(matches))

# [('team1', 'team2'), ('team1', 'team3'), ('team1', 'team4'), ('team2', 'team1'), ...]
```

You can then find matches against your previous team:

```py
previous_team = "team2"

current_team = "team3"

awkward = [previous_team in match and current_team in match for match in matches]

print(awkward)
```